# In given trapezoid $AD=DC$ and areas shown are equal , $BD=?$

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is right-angled trapezoid. $AD=DC$ and $S_{DCGH}=S_{AFEB}$  (where $S$ is area).If $HG=6$ and $FE=7$ , find $BD$ .

[image: 1]

I did the following:

[image: 2]

Finding $a^2+b^2$ is enough,so I thought doing as below would give the answer:

$(a+b)a=(6+a)m+(7+b)n+13(a-(m+n))$

$a^2=m(a-7)+n(b-6)+a(13-b)$

But it doesn't work ,I also tried using trigonometry but it doesn't give the answer.Is there easy way to solve it,what would you offer?

Answer (score 2):

The two right-angled triangles which have respectively hypotenuses $CG$ and $EB$ are similar, hence their corresponding catheti are proportional, that is

$(6-a):(b-7)=m:n\;$,

$n=\dfrac{(b-7)m}{6-a}\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

On the other hand, since $\,S_{DCGH}=S_{AFEB}\,,\,$ it results that

$\dfrac{(a+6)m}2=\dfrac{(b+7)n}2\;$,

$(a+6)m=(b+7)n\;$,

and, from $\,(*)\,,\,$ it follows that

$(a+6)m=(b+7)\dfrac{(b-7)m}{6-a}\;,$

$(a+6)(6-a)=(b+7)(b-7)\;$,

$36-a^2=b^2-49\;$,

$a^2+b^2=85\;,$

$BD=\sqrt{85}\,.$